# How Can i add multiple event bus for rabbitMQ

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-3.1

startup.cs

```
services.AddSingleton<IRabbitMQPersistentConnection>(sp =>
        {
            var logger = 
sp.GetRequiredService<ILogger<DefaultRabbitMQPersistentConnection>> 
(); 
var factory = new ConnectionFactory()
{
  HostName = Configuration[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx], // IP
  DispatchConsumersAsync = true,
  UserName = Configuration["EventBusUserName"],
  Password = Configuration["EventBusPassword"]
}; 
var retryCount = 5; 
return new DefaultRabbitMQPersistentConnection(factory, logger, 
 retryCount);
});
```

above code is already exists in startup.cs I want modify for multiple event bus to send message. is there any way out ?##

Comment: [Could you check this repo?](https://github.com/Espent1004/eShopOnContainersCustomised/blob/335f43790238921f5eb52062644d3242b13b87ea/src/Services/Webhooks/Webhooks.API/Startup.cs#L243)